# draw line only in one direction starting with cgpoint

Tags: swift, line, uitouch, cgpoint, uigraphicscontext

My swifts codes goal below is to be able to draw a straight line. When the uiview is touch the user can only draw 90 degrees above the initial point. The direction has already ben decided. So the user can just draw the line above the point that is touched. You can the gif below the line on the left is what my code does below. The line on the right is what I would like to acheive.

[image]

```
import UIKit



class ViewController: UIViewController{
    
    
    
  
    
    var draw = Canvas()
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        [draw].forEach {
            view.addSubview($0)
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false}
    }
    
    
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        
        draw.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate ([
            
            
            
            draw.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            
            draw.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.77, constant: 0),
            draw.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
            draw.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant : 0),
            
            
            
        ])
        
        
        
        
    }
    
    
    
}



struct ColoredLine {
    var color = UIColor.black
    var points = [CGPoint]()
    var width = 5
}





class Canvas: UIView {
    
    
    var strokeColor = UIColor.red
    var strokeWidth = 5
    func undo() {
        _ = lines.popLast()
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
    
    func clear() {
        lines.removeAll()
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
    
    var lines = [ColoredLine]()
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
        
        lines.forEach { (line) in
            for (i, p) in line.points.enumerated() {
                if i == 0 {
                    context.move(to: p)
                } else {
                    context.addLine(to: p)
                }
            }
            
            context.setStrokeColor(line.color.cgColor)
            context.setLineWidth(CGFloat(line.width))
            context.strokePath()
            context.beginPath()
        }
        
        
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        var coloredLine = ColoredLine()
        coloredLine.color = strokeColor
        coloredLine.width = strokeWidth
        lines.append(coloredLine)
        
    }
    
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let point = touches.first?.location(in: self) else { return }
        guard var lastLine = lines.popLast() else { return }
        lastLine.points.append(point)
        lines.append(lastLine)
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is OK to manufacture the coordinates, Points consists of x and y.

Keeping the y, and done.

- keep the first point for one touch event

  ```
    var firstPt: CGPoint?

    //  get the first point
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let first = touches.first?.location(in: self) else { return }

        // store first as property 
        firstPt = first
    }
  ```
- manufacture the rest points, the x of new get points is irrelevant

  ```
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let point = touches.first?.location(in: self), let first = firstPt else { return }

        let pointNeeded = CGPoint(x:  first.x ,  y:  point.y)
        //  ... , do as usual
    }
  ```

and in `touchesEnd` and `touchesCancell`, `firstPt = nil`

Comment: can you add the property to your answer?

Comment: I added my code from touches end into the touches end method you provide. However my code is compiling but i cant draw anything.

Comment: your fault, debug yourself. I just pick the y val of the sample points